# Polynomial Sub-Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

Let $ V =\mathbb{R}_2[X]$ and $U = \{p\in V \mid p(-1) = p(2)\}$

Show that $U$ is a Linear Subspace of $V$ , and find a basis for $U$.

Complete the basis of $U$ to a basis of $V$.

I understand that all I need to do for the first part is find the basis, because every $p\in V$ . I am struggling with the polynomial format , and completing the basis.

Comment: You must firstly show it to he a subspace. That is closure under addition and scalar multiplication hold. To test this, you must know the following two properties of functions: $$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$$ $$(fg)(x) = f(x)g(x) $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. Then $p \in U \iff p(-1)=p(2) \iff b=-a.$

A Basis for $U$ is, for example, $\{1,x^2-x\}.$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: I get very confused with the notation of polynomials, in order for me to show that the new sequence is Linearly Independent I must show that a , b, c are 0 for any p(x) = 0 ?